# How to add space between PDB coordinates only when there is no space in between?

Tags: python, formatting, coordinates, biopython, pdb

The software I'm using does not accept the input when any two of the XYZ coordinates have no space in between. For example, "38.420  -6.206-108.383" can only be processed when written as "38.420  -6.206 -108.383."
Since I have 1000+ PDB files to process and each contain hundreds of lines of coordinates, I'm desperately in need of an efficient way to detect whether there needs to be a space added in between any two coordinates, and if so, insert one space.
After inserting the space, the old coordinates in an ".inp" file needs to be replaced with the new coordinates to serve as the input.

How can I possibly realize this using python?

I tried to manually change the coordinates but then realized it was virtually impossible... And the following code does work but it only pastes the original coordinates without inserting space when it's necessary.

The current code is as follows:

'''

```
input = open("hole.inp").readlines()
old_cpoint = input[16][7:29]

for i in range(1002):
    with open(dir + str(i) + '.pdb') as file:
        c = file.readlines()
        new_cpoint = c[2849][31:54]

        f_a = open("hole_"+str(i)+".inp").read()
        f_a = f_a.replace(str(old_cpoint),str(new_cpoint))
        f_b = open("hole_"+str(i)+".inp", 'w')
        f_b.write(f_a)
        f_b.close()
```

'''

Comment: Do the coordinates always have dashes? If they don't have dashes, how would you know what is x, y and z in "38.4206.206108.383" - can you make any assumptions of the length of those coordinates? It's possible if for example there are always 3 digits after the dot, or if the dashes are always there (and I can quickly post a solution). I don't think it's possible if you can't differentiate between each coordinate's start / end.

Comment: Yes. Typically the coordinates look like this: "30.604  -29.297  76.055"
Always 3 digits after the decimal point; and most of the time there is 1-2 spaces in between. The only exception is when two columns have a "-" sign, which takes up the space as shown in the original example. 
Thanks Kacper in advance!

Comment: Correction: space(s) get filled up when there are two "-" signs AND one coordinate has 3 digits before the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Please have a look at this solution - hopefully it will be enough to successfully parse all your data. You should use the `parse_coordinates` function. I tried to be explicit with the comments but let me know if something is unclear!

```
# Declare the string separator to insert it between the coordinates
SEPARATOR = " "

# Declare the offset - there are always 3 digits after the dots - it will be used to distinguish each coordinate
OFFSET = 3


def parse_coordinates(data):

    # You can remove this line if you don't need to save a copy of your data
    data = data.copy()

    # Iterate over the coordinates - we will need the iterator ("i") to access and modify the elements at each position
    for i, coordinates in enumerate(data):

        # Since there are always 3 coordinates we can extract the information about first 2 dots and add the offset
        sep_index_0 = coordinates.find(".") + OFFSET + 1
        sep_index_1 = coordinates.find(".", sep_index_0 + 1) + OFFSET + 1

        # Insert the separator if needed - need to increase sep_index_1 because the string is now longer
        if coordinates[sep_index_0] != SEPARATOR:
            coordinates = str.join(SEPARATOR, (coordinates[:sep_index_0], coordinates[sep_index_0:]))
            sep_index_1 += 1

        # Similarly for the second place where there should be a separator, except no need to increase the index anymore
        if coordinates[sep_index_1] != SEPARATOR:
            coordinates = str.join(SEPARATOR, (coordinates[:sep_index_1], coordinates[sep_index_1:]))

        # You haven't explicitly mentioned it, but this ensures there are single spaces
        coordinates = coordinates.replace(SEPARATOR * 2, SEPARATOR)

        # Modify the existing value to match the expected pattern
        data[i] = coordinates

    return data


# Read your input - can't really get simpler!
with open("input.in") as f:
    to_parse = f.readlines()

# Write to your output - this also makes sure there are exactly 2 spaces in the parsed coordinates
with open("output.out", "w") as f:
    for parsed_coordinates in parse_coordinates(to_parse):
        assert parsed_coordinates.count(SEPARATOR) == 2
        f.write(parsed_coordinates)
```

The input is as follows (Should be comprehensive enough but test it on your own as well!):

```
38.420 -6.206-108.383
38.420-6.206-108.383
38.420-6.206 -108.383
38.420 -6.206 -108.383
38.420 6.206 108.383
38.4206.206 108.383
38.420 6.206108.383
38.4206.206108.383
38.420  6.206  108.383
```

The output is as follows:

```
38.420 -6.206 -108.383
38.420 -6.206 -108.383
38.420 -6.206 -108.383
38.420 -6.206 -108.383
38.420 6.206 108.383
38.420 6.206 108.383
38.420 6.206 108.383
38.420 6.206 108.383
38.420 6.206 108.383
```

### Bonus

Some additional thoughts:

1. Avoid using `input` as a variable name - it's already a builtin function in Python
2. You are opening the files a little bit to much - avoid it as it will slow down the computations a lot
3. You might want to have a look at `os.path.join` to build the paths to your files - it's very simple to use and really useful

Comment: Thank you so much Kacper for the detailed answer, and I really appreciated the bonus thoughts! 
One last thing. I was trying to modify the pdb files without creating a new copy. It seems that the only way to modify is by using fileinput.input(data, inplace=1)? But I haven't been able to incorporate this function into parse_coordinates()...

Comment: You can just use `with open("file") as f` to read input and store it in the variable and then `with open("file", "w") as f` to wipe the file and write your parsed input.